# Use base_url with a model function

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm a rookie on codeigniter and I'm trying to solve a problem where I try to get some images from the database using a foreach cicle

I have this on my controller to get the images

```
$data['products'] = '.base_url('$this->Cart_model->get_img()').';
```

and this on my model

```
    public function get_img()
    {
        $sql  = "SELECT image FROM products";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

In my view it get me a syntax error beacause something is wrong in the controller

Already checked the View.tpl and everything is fine, must be something in the controller

Comment: where is your foreach? what is the error message?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/rmsuldao/public_html/application/controllers/Cart.php on line 305

Comment: `$data['products'] = $this->Cart_model->get_img();` see [Loading a Model](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html?highlight=model#loading-a-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot [the concatenation operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to concatenate the strings.

```
$data['products'] = '.base_url(' . $this->Cart_model->get_img() . ').';
```

Comment: you was right, it was the right syntax. Thanks
can you help me this error that shows after fixing that 
"Message: Array to string conversion"

Comment: If you have a separate problem not directly connected to the problem described in this question, you should open a new question and provide the data there.